# Error Installing sqlite3 1.3.9 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I am upgrading to rails 4, but run into the following issue when running bundle install.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby extconf.rb 
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.

   (root) at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
   (root) at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
   (root) at extconf.rb:3

extconf failed, uncaught signal 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/extensions/universal-java-1.6/1.9/sqlite3-1.3.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run 'gem install sqlite3 --version 1.3.9' I receive the same error. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
$ bundle install
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error, even after removing and reinstalling sqlite3.